# Function Of IF In Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

What is meaning of this formula in excel? I have tried to understand but I couldn't find solution.

```
 IF(D12>1;1;0)
```

Comment: IF(logical_test, value_if_true, value_if_false)

Comment: Can you try running it in excel?

Comment: thanks for your all efforts about that question. I have solved and understood it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IF function is one of the most popular functions in Excel, and it allows you to make logical comparisons between a value and what you expect.

`IF(D12>1;1;0)` means the following: If the value in the cell `D12` is bigger than `1` then display `1` otherwise display `0`.

You can get more information about each function when you click on the Insert function button in excel [image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your explanation it was fruitful.